# $\sigma^{-1} G \sigma$ relationship with $G$ and Aut$(X) \sigma \cap G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let Sym$(V)$ is a symmetric group over set $V = \{1,2,3\cdots ,n\}$ and $G$ is a subgroup of Sym$(V)$ i.e. $G \le$ Sym$(V)$. Let $\sigma \in $ Sym$(V)$, then what is $\sigma^{-1} G  \sigma$ relationship with $G$.

My questions :

1. Is $\sigma^{-1} G  \sigma$ group or coset ?
2. what is the relationship between $G$ and $\sigma^{-1} G  \sigma$ ?
3. what is Aut$(X) \sigma \cap G$ (Aut means automorphism group) ?

To me it looks that $\sigma^{-1} G  \sigma$ is a group not a coset (because $G\sigma$ is a coset) . But I am not able to prove this formally, please help

Comment: Let's see from the way I look at it, since $G$ is a group, the $\sigma$ is just a permutation of elements in $G$ so that doesn't damage the group structure. I think I would start this proof with a finite case first.

Comment: You can show it is a subgroup by checking that it satisfies the definition of  a subgroup. $G$ and $\sigma^{-1} G \sigma$ are called conjugate subgroups.

Comment: Note e.g. that $\sigma g_1\sigma^{-1}\cdot \sigma g_2\sigma^{-1}=\sigma g_1g_2\sigma^{-1}$